# Is it true that in Valmiki Ramayan Ram is described as only a human prince?

Tags: ramayana, rama

While in case of Krishna, it is 100 % explicit that he was avatar of Vishnu and god.

But in case of Ram, I have heard some people saying that Ram, in the Valimiki Ramayan is described only as a human prince/King. And not a avatar of Vishnu or God.
And that Ram is made god only in 16th Century AD Awadhi book Ramcharitmanas.

So, my question is -

1. Is Ram described as god or avatar of Vishnu in Valimiki Ramayan ?
2. Is Ram described as god in any other Puranas ?

Comment: The Avatar/God concept is puranic. I believe there are a lot of traditions that don't believe in it. A lot of actual interpretations don't believe in avatarvaad. So, what you consider as a god or not is totally up to specific sampradayas only. It doesn't extend beyond that and hence debatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Valmiki's Rama is explicitly Vishnu himself -

1. Word of Parashurama -

> **I have realized your touch of nature as that of the Immutable Supreme Being, God of Gods, the Exterminator of the demon Madhu,
> namely Vishnu,** by the touch of your handling that bow... oh,
> enemy-inflamer, blessedness alone betides you.

Sarga 76, Bala Kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.

Words of Brahma -

> "**You are the Lord Narayana himself** the glorious god, who wields the
> discus. You are the Divine Boar with a single tusk, the conqueror of
> your past and future enemies."
>
> **Seetha is no other than Goddess Lakshmi (the divine consort of Lord
> Vishnu), while you are Lord Vishnu.** You are having a shining dark-blue
> hue. You are the Lord of created beings. **For the destruction of
> Ravana, you entered a human body here, on this earth."**

Sarga 117, Yuddha kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.